# How to find available man chapter/section for a particular command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, redhat-enterprise-linux

For example: **ls** command have only chapter 1. while **mkdir** command have chapter 1 & 2. Is there any command which shows how many chapters are available for a particular command?

```
[root@localhost /]# man 1 ls
[root@localhost /]# man 2 ls
No entry for ls in section 2 of the manual
[root@localhost /]# man 3 ls
No entry for ls in section 3 of the manual
[root@localhost /]# man 4 ls
No entry for ls in section 4 of the manual
[root@localhost /]# man 5 ls
No entry for ls in section 5 of the manual
[root@localhost /]# man 6 ls
No entry for ls in section 6 of the manual
[root@localhost /]# man 7 ls
No entry for ls in section 7 of the manual
[root@localhost /]# man 8 ls
No entry for ls in section 8 of the manual

[root@localhost /]# man 1 mkdir
[root@localhost /]# man 2 mkdir
[root@localhost /]# man 3 mkdir
No entry for mkdir in section 3 of the manual
[root@localhost /]# man 4 mkdir
No entry for mkdir in section 4 of the manual
[root@localhost /]# man 5 mkdir
No entry for mkdir in section 5 of the manual
[root@localhost /]# man 6 mkdir
No entry for mkdir in section 6 of the manual
[root@localhost /]# man 7 mkdir
No entry for mkdir in section 7 of the manual
[root@localhost /]# man 8 mkdir
No entry for mkdir in section 8 of the manual
```

Comment: This isn't actually a duplicate I believe. He wants a chapter count, not a location

Comment: @JourneymanGeek If you call `man -a -w $command` that's what you'll get, so it's a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

You use `apropos -e ls` - this is for exact matches, and filters out a lot of stiff The [apropos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apropos_%28Unix%29) command will search through manpage titles for a string. The number next to the entry in question is the number of chapters, I believe- for example when I run `apropos -e mkdir`

```
mkdir (1)            - make directories
mkdir (2)            - create a directory
```

While the output of `apropos -e ls` shows

```
dircolors (1)        - color setup for ls
ls (1)               - list directory contents
```

I admit I've not been able to work out if the number in the bracket next to the name of the command is the chapter number, but this would be the command to use.

Comment: Thanks for your positive reply! I have tried **apropos** but -e is not working. Also checked with man apropos it doesn't show any such parameter. Please could you provide more guide on that as well. Many thanks.

Comment: This is odd since I got it off the man page. Try it without the e, as per my earlier edit, and look through the output.